# I want to find all pairs of integer $ (x, y)$

Tags: number-theory

My number theory professor gives me a exercise

Show that for any prime $p$ there exist integer pair $(x, y)$ such that $x^2+y^2\equiv3 \pmod p$

I think I need more information about $x, y$ But professor says " we can prove it by Quadratic raciprocity law

please give me some hints or solution

Comment: Your title says you want all pairs, but the body just says to prove there is one pair.  Which is it?

Comment: I'm sorry that i have short english.

Comment: I wanna say there exist (x, y)

Comment: For $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, you can select $x^2=-1$ and $y^2=4$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** There are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ values of $a$ which are quadratic residues $\pmod{p}$. There are $\frac{p+1}{2}$ values of $a$ such that $3-a$ is a quadratic residues $\pmod{p}$.

Show that there is at least an $a$ so that both $a$ and $3-a$ are quadratic residues modulo $p$.